# EBS - Restore from Snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

When restoring an EBS volume from snapshot can you use the latest snapshot only (i.e. the one with the last incremental block changes) and do you need to have kept all previous snapshots (including the orginal)?

This seems to suggest you can  but want to check
http://www.nimbo.com/blog/observations-ebs-snapshot-restore-behavior-aws/

So as an example, I have a RAID 0 with 4 EBS volumes I snapshot day 1. I take daily snapshots for several months with an S3 lifecycle policy that deletes snapshots after 1 month. Month 3 i want to restore these volumes to a day in month 2 to be used by a seperate instance. Will this work? Or do i need a history of all the snapshots?

Answer (score 1):

First, EBS snapshots are stored in S3, but not in any S3 bucket that you have control of. You can't use S3 lifecycle policies to control EBS snapshot retention. You have to use the EBS API or console to manage EBS snapshots.

Given that, AWS manages your EBS snapshot history for you. Any EBS snapshot that exists in your account is able to be restored, and does not depend on you having kept previous snapshots around. When you delete a historical snapshot that another snapshot depends on, Amazon handles that behind the scenes in such a way that you can still restore any snapshots you haven't deleted.

Comment: Thanks Mark - is there a charge for these snapshots then , i had always assumed there would be an S3 charge? And as above can you use the console to use any snapshot over time? Does it list them all ?

Comment: There is a storage charge for snapshots that shows up on your bill separate from your S3 charges. And yes, all snapshots are listed in the EC2 console under Snapshots, and you can restore any snapshot in your account at any time.

Comment: Great, so you could still delete them over time to avoid storage charges (i.e monthly) but still be able to do the restore?

Comment: No, you can't restore a snapshot you have deleted, but **you can freely delete any snapshot without losing the use of any other snapshot of the same volume**.  Snapshots do not "contain" data -- they are lists of pointers to backup data blocks stored by EBS (not directly accessible to you) in S3.  A data block referenced by pointers from multiple snapshots is billed only 1x its size each month (not 1x for each referencing shapshot). Once a data block is referenced by 0 pointers, due to deletion of all dependent snapshots, it is purged and no longer billed.